# Remove duplicate remote notifications from notification center

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm using Google Cloud Messaging for notifications in my app and i have many type of notifications. is there a way to display only the last notification of each type in notification center to not have duplication ?

Answer (score 0):

No, an app has no ability to access or control the content of the notification center.